# Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Tags: python

Ok, so I decided to use selenium for some code, but it doesn't work. When I put the chromedriver in my path, manually, it still doesn't work. can anyone help. PS: I already pip installed selenium.

Also, I watch/read the other article on stack overflow about this problem, but it didn't help me.

Comment: Did you use this format `webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/path/to/chromedriver.exe')`

Answer (score 0):

If you put `chromedriver` in the home directory of the user running it, that should work.  Would be helpful if you stated in your question what OS/version you are using.

Comment: Sure. Im using a Windows 10, Python 3.8

Answer (score 0):

Well add change the code to this

```py
import os

path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + r'\chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path)
```

So what is does is it add the chrome webdriver from path to selenium webdriver. Make sure to add the `chromedriver.exe` file in the root of the folder.

Comment: how do I add the chromedriver in the root of the folder? Is it the folder I'm running? Because I didn't download selenium, but I pip installed it.

Comment: The root of the current working directory...root of the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when the .py file you are running cannot find chrome driver. the best thing you can do in this situation is that the chrome driver that you installed copy and paste it in same folder as your .py file and then keep your path blank. if you keep your path blank it basically means that the .py file will search the driver on in its folder so make sure you have chrome driver in the same folder ask .py file and then keep your web driver as:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Comment: No can do sherlock. So I put it in that same folder, but how do I keep the path blank?

Comment: driver = webdriver.Chrome() Keep like this thats wut i do becoz while making .exe or something and giving to other PC you wont know which path or where the file has been downloaded so keep the path blank like that and put chrome driver in the sem folder. I hope you understand

Comment: But even after I added that line of code, it still gives me a problem,

Comment: did replace it or add. you need to replace it instead of "webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/path/to/chromedriver.exe')' if it still doesn't work post the code in the question I will try helping you I cant help much as I don't have the code.